# Python class function return super()

Tags: python, python-3.x, design-patterns, super, readonly

So I was messing around with a readonly-modifyable class pattern which is pretty common in `java`. It involves creating a base class containig readonly properties, and extending that class for a modifyable version. Usually there is a function `readonly()` or something simular to revert a modifyable-version back to a readonly-version of itself.

Unfortunately you cannot directly define a setter for a property defined in a super class in python, but you can simply redefine it as shown below. Mor interestingly In python you got the 'magic function' `super` returning a proxy-object of the parent/super class which allows for a cheecky `readonly()` implementation which feels really hacky, but as far as I can test it just works.

```py
class Readonly:
    _t:int
    
    def __init__(self, t: int):
        self._t = t
    
    @property
    def t(self) -> int:
        return self._t



class Modifyable(Readonly):
    def __init__(self, t: int):
        super().__init__(t)
    
    @property
    def t(self) -> int:
        return self._t # can also be super().t
    
    @t.setter
    def t(self, t):
        self._t = t
    
    def readonly(self) -> Readonly:
        return super()
```

In the above pattern I can call the `readonly` function and obtain a proxy to the parent object without having to instantiate a readonly version. The only problem would be that when setting the readonly-attribute instead of throwing `AttributeError: can't set attribute`, it will throw a `AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '<param-name>'`

So here are the question for this:

- Can this cause problems (exposing the `super` proxy-object outside the class itself)?
- I tested this on python 3.8.5, but not sure if that is by accident and goes against the 'python-semantics' so to speak?
- Is there a better/more desirable way to achieve this? (I have no idea if its even worth the ambiguous error message in ragards to performance for example)

I Would love to hear opinions and/or insights into this

Comment: It's not really clear to me what exactly you are trying to do here. It seems that you consider both a) returning `super()` or 2) returning a `Readonly` instance acceptable, but those are very different cases. The former will provide a proxy to the view the *mutable* object as readonly, but the latter will provide a separate *immutable* object. Are you looking for something akin to casting, i.e. treating the exact same object as of its base type?

Comment: The main focus is to return a 'readonly' version of the class. In java that means a different object, which can also be done in python. I happened to stumble on the `super()` trick hence the question if it is worth the 'cheezy' approuch in terms of for example performance. I am always curious as to how far a language/API can go before breaking, and what is considered 'normal' and what not.

Answer (score 2):

> Can this cause problems (exposing the super proxy-object outside the
> class itself)?

Not directly.  But a super() object sometimes can behave in strange ways sometimes. If all you want are attributes guarded by `property` it will work, but, for example, if you have a simple instance attribute, accessed directly, (as is the more usual pattern in Python), it won't work with the super() proxy.

> I tested this on python 3.8.5, but not sure if that is by accident and
> goes against the 'python-semantics' so to speak?

No, the behaviors you are relying on are pretty consistent, from 3.0 (and even before) onwards (including Python 3.12 alpha)

> Is there a better/more desirable way to achieve this? (I have no idea
> if its even worth the ambiguous error message in ragards to
> performance for example)

Yes.
As you can see, this will not deliver a readonly version of your sub-class, it will rather return an super-proxy, which will behave mostly as an instance of the parent class.

If returning an instance of the parent class is enough, and being modifiable are the only differences, you can create a new read-only instance, load it with the current instance values - this would work:

```
def readonly(self):
    # retrieves the superclass without name hardcoding
    # this is the actual class, not a proxy:
    parent = __class__.__mro__[1]
    # creates an instance without going though it's `__init__`:
    instance = parent.__new__(parent)
    # updates the instance `__dict__` internally:
    instance.__dict__.update(self.__dict__)
    return instance
```

The `__dict__.update()` thing to effectuate the clonning will look unsafe, but it is pretty reliable. Python serialization tool - pickle - itself uses this approach when unserializing objects (by default - classes can customize that.

Another option, this is "less recomended" because...maybe it can scare people, but is pretty reliable, and will work, is to change your instance itself to be an instance of `ReadOnly` when .readonly is called.

Just write `readonly` as:

```
der readonly(self):
     self.__class__ = __class__.__mro__[1]
     return self
```

If changing the class is not desirable at all, there is the option to have a state in the "modifiable" class itself that would switch it being writable or not. Upon callign `readonly` you could either create a new read-only instance, or change the state internally.

The simpler way of doing this is just use another attribute, prefixed with `_`, and test it with an `if` in the setter.

If there are a lot of such attributes, of course that is undersirable, you can customize `__setattr__` to catch all assignements -or create a custom-descriptor, instead of `property` to do that.

TBH, if the my goal is to have an editable object that at some point should no longer be editable, I would go with the `__class__` changing approach above. If you are using typing, use `typing.cast` along with the `.__class__` assignment so that static tools can understand it.